# Discord js how to run mp3 when i'm connected to voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
client.on(Events.MessageCreate, async message => {
  if (message.author.id === '1111111111111111111111111111111' && message.content.slice(-1) === '!') {
    const guild = message.guild;
    const channels = guild.channels.cache;
    let channelToPlayIn;

    for (const [channelId, channel] of channels) {
      if (channel.type === 2 && channel.members.size > 0) {
       channelToPlayIn = channel;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (channelToPlayIn) {
        const connection =  joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: channelToPlayIn.id,
        guildId: channelToPlayIn.guild.id,
        adapterCreator: channelToPlayIn.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        selfDeaf: false,
      });


      setTimeout(() => connection.destroy(), 5_000);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the way i connecte the bot in voice channal and this part work but i don't how to run mp3 file while the bot is connected

I tried use createAudioRessource and createAudioPlayer but none of them seems to work when i tried them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before you implement some new code take some simple measures:

**1.** Check if the bot has speak permissions enabled. (admin works as well)

**2** Make sure that the createAudioResource/createAudioPlayer are ran after the bot is connected to the channel. (assuming you commence the play once join)

**3** Make sure that the .mp3 file you are using actually exists and can be played.

---

***What you can do if these approaches do not work***

Similar to the discord.js v13 used here (assuming you are on 13 and not 14): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riyHsgI2IDs&ab_channel=CodeLyon

Use a url to a video or google drive where you will run the mp3. v13 and v14 do not work well with mp3s that you have on your computer as the bot must grab it from your computer making this inefficient etc.

Also, if you *still* want to use mp3s from your own computer, simply don't. The best solution is to simply use urls and if discord.js does not work well with mp3s from a someone's own computer and you must instead install a seperate npm music player to grab mp3s and then play it on the computer.

---

I hope this helps you and anyone else who happens to see this and have a wonderful day. If it doesn't comment what you want in more detail and if you are using v13 or v14. Also, it would help if you could explain **why** it must be a mp3 file from your computer if it must be.

Comment: First, thank for your answer. I use discord v14, and it had to be mp3 file because i made the sound, but i can use url too.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds good. So is your plan just to use a url?

Comment: Yes it what i'll do